# What does the optimizer do with hash join and full outer join?

Tags: oracle, database-performance, sql-tuning

What does the optimizer do with hash join and full outer join?

As far as I know, with Hash Join and Outer Join, hash table is built for the one whose nonmatching rows will NOT return, what if both nonmatching rows will return ?

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13436236/14955

Comment: Also https://sqlity.net/en/1490/a-join-a-day-the-hash-join/: " The Hash Join algorithm is able to handle any of the logical join types. If the join is a Left Outer Join, a Full Outer Join or a Left Anti Semi Join, a marker is added to each row in the hash index to keep track of rows that had a match. At the end of the join process a single scan of the hash index will return all unmatched rows. "